# Alarm not being stopped even after calling AlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm

I have this local variables:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager;
static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private String TAG = "netwatcher";
private final int alarmId = 0;
```

Here is were I start my alarm

```
    private void startNetWatcher(){ //runs every 30 seconds
    Log.i(TAG, "starting Net Watcher");
    Intent alarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NetWatcher.class);
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), alarmId, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if(!alarmRunning) {
        Log.i(TAG, "alarm not running");
        if (pendingIntent == null)
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), alarmId, alarm,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 15000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The alarm is working great, here is the code where I "stop" the alarm (or at least try to). However it is not working, because it still runs the service that was supposed to be stopped when I stopped the alarm.

```
       private void stopNetWatcher(){
    Log.i(TAG, "stopping net watcher because app is on front: " + alarmId);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NetWatcher.class);
    if (pendingIntent==null)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), alarmId, alarm,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "intent stopped");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, try by removing the null check for pending intent " if (pendingIntent==null) ".

Comment: @kukroid still not working.